# How to Compare Two Dates, and if Equal Give Toaster in JavaScript Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**In the code below, the date in the database is of `date` type:**

```
           function remainderCheck() {
                    $interval(function() {
                var i = 0;
                      for (i; i < $scope.notes.length; i++) {
                        var currentDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
                    console.log("currentDate" + currentDate);
                //              console.log($scope.notes[i].title);
                        var dateString = (new              Date($scope.notes[i].remainder));
                        var dateString2=new 
                   Date(dateString).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
                    console.log("database date::"+dateString2);
                        if (dateString2 >   currentDate) {
                console.log($scope.notes[i].description);
                console.log("reminder !!!!! ");
                toastr.success('Remainder heck notes!!!');
            }
            console.log("dskjhdjkh");

        }
    }, 10000);
}
remainderCheck();
```

How do I compare these two dates?

```
currentDate2017-11-29 15:26
database date::2017-11-13 18:30:00
```

The output of the code is shown above, but I'm not able to compare both.

I want to enable Toaster if both times are same.

Answer (score 1):

What about

**Compare dates only**

```
var dbDate='2017-11-23 18:30:00';

if(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')==moment(dbDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
alert("Equal")
else
alert("Not equal")
```

**DateTime Compare**

```
 var dbDate='2017-11-23 18:30:00';

if(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')==moment(dbDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))
alert("Equal")
else
alert("Not equal")
```

Comment: I think you were looking for [isSame](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) instead